# What does 'MSO' and 'MSE' mean?

Tags: support, terminology

I've seen the user “Community♦︎︎“ edit questions before and said 'migration of MSO to MSE links' in the edit desc. What does this mean?[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arqade is part of Stack Exchange, commonly abbreviated to SE. For many years, Meta Stack Overflow (**MSO**) was **also** used for questions about the entire Network of sites.

Eventually, this was changed. Stack Overflow got it's own, fresh meta site, and MSO became Meta Stack Exchange (***MSE**).

Just on the topic of those specific edits: to prevent broken links, the devs ran a script which updated all the previous links to MSO to point to MSE (as per the edit history you've found)

Comment: Oh thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: The second revision by the bot was to fix the mistake they made the first time :)